# Oracle SQL remove trailing new line

Tags: oracle, line, new-operator, trailing

I'm creating an ssrs form in oracle sql on which I need to list an address. New lines have to remain in the address however I can't find the way of removing new lines at the end of the address.

Example of what I have:

```
10 Donkey Kong,
London,
XX1 1XX
new line
new line
```

Example of what I want:

```
10 Donkey Kong,
London,
XX1 1XX
```

Oracle version: 11g - release 11.2

I tried already:

- **`trim(both chr(10) from (trim(both chr(13) from a.address))`** - it doesnt make any difference
- **`substr(a.address,1,length(translate(a.address,'d'||chr(10)||chr(13),'d')))`** - translate checks how many spaces is in the whole address and substring only returns part of the address because it cuts more than it should

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer :D

Regex to the rescue.

```
regexp_replace(a.address,'[' || chr(10) || chr(13) || ' ]+$', '')
```

I would still like to know why trim didn't work. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here with the pattern `\s+$` here:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET address = REGEXP_REPLACE(address, '\s+$', '');
```

I can speculate a few reasons why your trim approach is failing.  First of all, perhaps not every column value has CRLF (`CHR(10) || CHR(13)`).  Instead, it could have a Linux line ending, which is just `CHR(13)`.  Or, there could be other types of whitespace present at the end.  The answer I gave is simpler and should cover you in all edge cases.

Comment: I was considering that too. So i ran replace(replace(a.address,chr(13),'X'),chr(10),'Y'). I got the address with XYXY at the end :D So it's definitely a 10 and 13.